# C# Entity Framework use nested property as foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Sales { get; set; }
}

public class Listing {
    public int ListingId { get; set; }
    
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class Order {
    public int ListingId { get; set; }
    public Listing Listing { get; set; }
    
    public int BuyerId { get; set; }
    public User Buyer { get; set; }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Buyer)
    .WithMany(e => e.Orders)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.BuyerId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Listing.User)
    .WithMany(e => e.Sales)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.Listing.UserId);
```

I am having trouble configuring the relationship for the `User.Sales` property.

The code above should explain what I'm trying to do but the `e.Listing.User` and `e.Listing.UserId` parts do not work.

I know I can solve the problem by introducing `SellerId` and `Seller` properties to the `Order` class but that feels like a waste because these are accessible through the `Listing` property, specifically through `Order.Listing.UserId` and `Order.Listing.User` respectively.

Is there a way to configure the relationship without that?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at that model, Sales belongs on Listing, not User. A User has many Orders, linking back via the Buyer. When it comes to Sold items, that is via the Listings. If you want all Sales for a user then you would use:

```
var salesForUser = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Listing.User.UserId == userId)
    .ToList();
```

... for example.  When loading a user and wanting eager access their sales, `.Include(o => o.Listings).ThenInclude(l => l.Sales)`.